# Foselastica get only best matching child

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

**NOTE: elasticsearch 1.7 and foselastica 3.1 is used!**

How do I get only the best matching child in parent/child or nested? 
I need to query the whole index (parent and chied fields). The query returns parents, and their children. But I only need parent and best matching child for the query.

I've tried to achieve it with TopChildren, HasChild and so on, but its not working.

This is what my query looks like

```
{
   "query":{
      "has_child":{
         "type":"variants",
         "query":{
            "filtered":{
               "query":{
                  "bool":{
                     "must":[
                        {
                           "match":{
                              "allField":{
                                 "query":"shirt rot",
                                 "operator":"AND",
                                 "minimum_should_match":"80%",
                                 "fuzziness":"0.8",
                                 "analyzer":"custom_search_analyzer"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ],
                     "should":[
                        {
                           "match":{
                              "shortName":{
                                 "query":"shirt rot",
                                 "operator":"AND",
                                 "analyzer":"custom_search_analyzer",
                                 "boost":5
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               },
               "filter":{
                  "bool":{
                     "should":[
                        {
                           "terms":{
                              "customized":[
                                 0
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "max_children":1
      }
   }
}
```